# CherryPy with HTTP digest authentication stuck on status 400 Bad Request

Tags: http-headers, cherrypy, http-authentication

I implemented HTTP digest authentication in my CherryPy application using the built-in `tools.auth_digest` tool.  This was easy and seemed to work well as I tested during the day.

This evening, I attempted to access the application from the same browser I used earlier today (but from a different IP address).  For whatever reason I was prompted for credentials.  I may have entered the wrong password but, again for whatever reason, I got into the situation where my browser is sending an authentication header with each request, but with `username=""`.

Cherrypy responds to this with a status of 400 Bad Request.

I'm now in a situation where I can't enter new credentials to get into the site (with this browser — I can use a browser that's not "polluted" with the bad authorization header without trouble).  To enter new credentials, my understanding is that CherryPy should return 401 Unauthorized, which should prompt the browser to request credentials.

My two part question is:

1. What can I do to clear the authorization info on my browser?
2. Am I correct that the correct response to this situation should be 401 Unauthorized rather than 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Did you try restarting your browser? Clearing cookies and cache?

Comment: Thank you.  I am prepared to swear that yesterday, when I first implemented the digest authentication, that my browser was persisting the authentication across browser sessions.  Testing today, however, indicates that the browser *does* clear the authentication tokens (as I would have expected).  (This is http authentication, so not cookie related, but closing the browser is a perfectly acceptable log out solution)  If you repost your comment as an answer I will be glad to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Perception in the comments, the browser will forget the credentials when closed.  I'm guessing that when I tested this and thought I saw the browser remembering credentials between browser sessions that I must have had Chrome open in several different windows simultaneously.